# Cannot import sklearn in my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I installed **anaconda** and started working on **jupyter notebook**.

When i try and import **sklearn** i get the **error** shown in the **image** (note that i didn't had any problems importing other packages).

I've done a bit of research online and from my understanding i believe the issue exists because i already have **sklearn** installed on **Python** and there's a possible **conflict**.

If that's the case i don't know what to do since i already use **sklearn** on another project and i cannot uninstall it.

Anyone know how i can solve this issue? 
Thanks in advance!

[image: OSERROR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might face the same issue, check your **Anaconda** and **Python**.

I had **Anaconda** on **64-bit** and i didn't knew that by **default** **Python** is **downloaded** on **32-bit**.

After uninstalling and installing **Anaconda** to **32-bit** everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the traceback, there are two python environments involved here:

```
~\AppData\roaming\python\Python37
~\anaconda3
```

Please make sure your PATH is clean and you can actually remove one of them first.